# Nesting And Or in Mongodb Not working

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$search_string="aaaa";
$searchQuery = array(
'$and' => array(
        'ispublished'=>"1",
        '$or' => array(
        array(
            'title' => new MongoRegex("/^$search_string/i"),
            ),
            array(
                'description' => new MongoRegex("/^$search_string/i"),
                )
                                                )
                                    )
                                        );
```

this is giving error saying bad query. I want the resullts that have ispublished 1 and (title having aaaa or description having aaaa)

Answer (score 0):

Actually above coding have syntax error, some braces are not closed

Please try below

```
$search_string="aaaa";
$searchQuery = array(
'$and' => array(
        'ispublished'=>"1",
        '$or' => array(
        array(
            'title' => new MongoRegex("/^$search_string/i"),
            ),
            array(
                'description' => new MongoRegex("/^$search_string/i"),
                )
                                                )

                                        ));
```

Comment: are you defined the MongoRegex class ? http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php

Comment: Everything is working fine when i remove ispublished=>1 but i need that condition

Comment: select * from abctable where (name like %aaaa% or place like %aaaa% ) and ispublished=1
I am making a query like this in mongodb

Comment: @Amanjot Well the "anchor" `^` caret in the regex is pinning matches to the "start" of the string so the search is more like `name like "aaaa%"`. If you want anywhere in the string then remove the caret. Un-pinned and case-insensitive matches are bad for MongoDB or any database as an index cannot be used to effectively filter without scanning all content. Possibly you should look at "text search", but of course for real words. Which is why you should not use abstract data in questions.

Comment: @BlakesSeven can u give me an example how i should write %aaaa% in regex

Comment: @Amanjot I did. Remove the caret `/aaaa/` and add the "i" if you want case insensitive.